# GCP cloud build: CLOUD_BUILD_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I try to run `cloud deploy` on existing project where also run Cloud Build and

I have the following error:

```yaml
targetRenders:
  qsdev:
    failureCause: CLOUD_BUILD_UNAVAILABLE
    renderingState: FAILED
```

I try to use this [article](https://cloud.google.com/deploy/docs/deploy-app-gke?hl=en_US) when I try to run a `cloud deploy` on a new empty project everything works as expected.

I understand that the problem is with the permissions but can’t find where exactly.

I used this [help](https://cloud.google.com/deploy/docs/cloud-deploy-service-account#required_permissions)

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you try to deactivate and reactivate the Cloud Build API?

Comment: Unfortunately not, we will lost objects in google build

Comment: lost object? What do you mean?

Comment: we build images there, if I deactivate API all images will delete

Comment: No, the image aren't stored in Cloud Build, but stored elsewhere (Artifact registry most of the time). Cloud Build is only a processing service. You could lost trigger configuration, and, even, I'm not sure!

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the [FailureCause](https://cloud.google.com/deploy/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.deliveryPipelines.releases.rollouts.jobRuns#failurecause) documentation, this error is caused by insufficient permissions.

> **CLOUD_BUILD_UNAVAILABLE**: Cloud Build is not available, either because it is not enabled or because Google Cloud Deploy has insufficient permissions. See [Required permission](https://cloud.google.com/deploy/docs/cloud-deploy-service-account#required_permissions).

In the [required permission](https://cloud.google.com/deploy/docs/cloud-deploy-service-account#required_permissions) documentation, it shows some troubleshoot steps to follow in order to ensure that the correct permissions are set:

> - The service account used for rendering configurations must have sufficient permissions to access the Cloud Storage bucket where your Google Cloud Deploy resources are stored (delivery pipelines, releases, rollouts).
>   The role `roles/clouddeploy.jobRunner` includes all permissions the render service account ([`privatePool` or `defaultPool`](https://cloud.google.com/deploy/docs/config-files#target_definitions)) needs.
> - The service account used for deploying must have sufficient permissions to deploy to the target cluster, *and* permission to access the Cloud Storage bucket.
>   **Note:** If you use a custom Cloud Storage bucket, you can put it anywhere. (It doesn't need to be in the same region, for example, as the delivery pipeline.)
> - The service account that calls Google Cloud Deploy to create a release must have the `clouddeploy.releaser role`. It must also have the `iam.serviceAccount.actAs` permission to use the service account that renders manifests (for example through the `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser` role).
> - The service account that calls Google Cloud Deploy to promote a release or create a rollout must have the `iam.serviceAccount.actAs` permission to use the service account that deploys to targets.